# How to stop IE from 'selecting' first required option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer decides to use first available option as a 'placeholder' rather than leave the select blank like Chrome does for example.

Without my manually hidden option
`<option value="" ng-if="false">Don't display a blank option</option>`, there would be a blank option I don't want to see on a required select field. I want to give user 2 options and not let them see an empty option.

How can I force IE into not selecting first required option. I don't want to involve javascript to selectIndex -1 everywhere because I have plenty of those select fields around.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

  $scope.options = [
    {id:1, label: 'Option1'},
    {id:2, label: 'Option2'}
  ];

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="option" required id="opt" name="opt" ng-options="option as option.label for option in options track by option.id">
      <option value="" ng-if="false">Don't display a blank option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the first select option disabled:

```
<option value="" selected disabled>(placeholder text, if you want)</option>
```

This would technically give the user three options instead of two, although they won't be able to select the disabled one.

Comment: Yeah, not really a solution I've been looking for. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: That's the point of my required field. You can't select nothing or see that nothing is available but initially want it to be blank like it is in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

A really clean way would be to intialize your `option` model in your Controller.
Something like the following should work:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

  $scope.option = '';
  $scope.options = [
    {id:1, label: 'Option1'},
    {id:2, label: 'Option2'}
  ];

});
```